# how to call a particular data source method of UICollectionview?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, reloaddata

`UICollectionView` can `reloadData`. But, I just want to reload `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Use bool variables for your requirement. You cant call particular datasource methods.

Comment: Why you are not reloading whole collection view? Any reason ?

Comment: @NSPratik because I am loading URL images in cellForItemAtIndexPath and I want dynamic collection cell size. So once all the images are downloaded, I want to resize the cell according to image size.

Comment: Try to get resolution size before downloading..

Answer (score 0):

you can use these methods invalidateIntrinsicContentSize and layoutIfNeeded for more read documentation